# USB WebCam not detected in Android devices

Tags: webcam, webcam-capture, logitech, uvc

I Created an UVC based application to connect USB External webcam [Logitech c170] with android device. I Follow the coding from this [link](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera). After building the project did Native NDK Build operations and copied the libs folder in to my directory.

The program was built and run successfully, but it would not shown USB connectivity in with my Tablet.

In device_filter.xml file ,i also included product id and vendor id of my webcam (Vendor id  : 046D ,product id : 082B).

How to connect my WEBCAM into android device. Guide me!!

Thanks in Advance !..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ya i got the exact answer that what i want. !! i chosen a right link for UVC web cam for Android. Follow the steps :

[image]

**Note** : Step 6 link is [here](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera) .

Happy Coding!!